# Cannot connect to Grapevine from another computer on the same network

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

I am using Grapevine 3.1.0 in VS2013. The project is called ConsoleApplication1.

After starting the server on my host machine, I can access it locally from `localhost:1234`, `127.0.0.1:1234`, and `192.168.1.2:1234` (my machine's local IP address). However, even after port forwarding, I cannot connect to my external IP from any machine. Furthermore, I cannot connect with the local IP address from another machine, only from the host.

I have even made a Windows Firewall rule for the program, but to no avail.

The following code is for the server portion. Attempts to connect are made using Firefox.

```
//Program.cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using Grapevine.Server;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new RESTServer(host: "*");
        server.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        server.Stop();
    }
}

public sealed class TestResource : RESTResource
{
    [RESTRoute]
    public void HandleAllGetRequests(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        SendTextResponse(context, "GET is a success!");
    }
}
```

`netstat -a` reports that the server is listening. I receive a timeout message from Firefox when attempting to connect from another machine on the same network. Looking at both the host and the other machine with Fiddler, I can tell that the host machine never received any form of message after attempting to make a connection.

I ensured that I am running the program in administrator mode, but it would throw an exception if I didn't regardless.

I have tested the server on Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.

What additional steps do I need to do in order to successfully run Grapevine?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running the application on?

Comment: I have updated the post above. I have tested the server on Windows 8.1 (main) and Windows 7.

Comment: Are you running your application from Visual Studio, or as a standalone executable?

Comment: I am running the executable (ConsoleApplication1.exe, not ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe) generated when I build the default release configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> I have even made a Windows Firewall rule for the program

Did you make a Windows Firewall rule for the **port**? If not, [**try this first**](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html). You *might* need to add the url to the ACL on the computer it's running on, which you can do by opening a terminal as admin and run:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:1234/ user=Everyone`